# python3 Illegal instruction (core dump)

Tags: python, linux, virtual-machine, python-3.5

I am on a virtual machine running on Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed pandas, sklearn, and conda using pip3. When I try to run a python3 program using these packages, I get the error "Illegal instruction (core dump)."

Not sure how to fix this. Simple python3 programs (aka no imports) run fine. I also tried importing but not using these packages, and that works.
The only other thing I have done on this VM is opencv development with C++.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Any solution ? @Joseph

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari I found a full reinstall (including of python) worked for me! Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure the source of the issue, I did a full purge of python3 and reinstalled it and all packages with it and that fixed the issue!

Comment: This happened to me when I built python myself using make (optimizations were on), and then cloned the virtual machine. Every time I make a new clone, it needs a recompiling.